# Which fuse is assigned for the 2012 VW Passat Infotainment console?

Tags: vw, fuse, passat, diagram, infotainment

My battery died, and after the jump start the Infotainment touchscreen (radio, cd, GPS, etc) console won't turn on. I suspect the fuse might be burnt. Which fuse is assigned to the Infotainment console system? Also, would be great if you can share the fuse diagram as well.

Comment: Have you checked the fuse box covers? there is often a legend given either molded into the plastic or a paper stuck on. If not what about the owners manual - that usually has the information.

Comment: Nothing in the manual. I have the repair manual and couldn't find it there either.